# implement onClickListener on maps markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using Google maps API V2 to populate a map with a list of places, whenever the user clicks a marker view it should take him to a new activity with more details. however I am having problems with implementing that
here my
 MapsActivity.java

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return null;
    //return prepareInfoView(marker);
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    //return null;
    return prepareInfoView(marker);

}

private View prepareInfoView(Marker marker){
    //prepare InfoView programmatically

     Restaurants restaurants = places.get(marker);
    Log.d(TAG,"restaurants1"+ restaurants.getName());

    LinearLayout infoView = new LinearLayout(MapsActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams infoViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    infoView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    infoView.setLayoutParams(infoViewParams);
    ImageView infoImageView = new ImageView(MapsActivity.this);
    //Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map);
    infoImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    infoView.addView(infoImageView);

    LinearLayout subInfoView = new LinearLayout(MapsActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams subInfoViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    subInfoView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    subInfoView.setLayoutParams(subInfoViewParams);

    TextView subInfoName = new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
    subInfoName.setText("Name: " +restaurants.getName());
    TextView subInfoCost = new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
    subInfoCost.setText("Cost: "  + restaurants.getCost() +"€");
    TextView subInfoCuisine = new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
    subInfoCuisine.setText("Cuisine: " +restaurants.getMenuType());
    TextView subInfoPhone = new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
    subInfoPhone.setText("Phone: " +restaurants.getPhone());
    subInfoView.addView(subInfoName);
    subInfoView.addView(subInfoPhone);
    subInfoView.addView(subInfoCost);
    subInfoView.addView(subInfoCuisine);
    infoView.addView(subInfoView);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, RestaurantDetailsActivity.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "lat" + restaurants.getLat());
    Log.d(TAG, "lng" + restaurants.getLng());
    intent.putExtra("id", restaurants.getId());
    intent.putExtra("name", restaurants.getName());
    intent.putExtra("phone", restaurants.getPhone());
    intent.putExtra("lat", restaurants.getLat());
    intent.putExtra("lng", restaurants.getLng());
    intent.putExtra("address1", restaurants.getAddress1());
    intent.putExtra("address2", restaurants.getAddress2());
    intent.putExtra("offer", restaurants.getOffer());
    intent.putExtra("menu_type", restaurants.getMenuType());
    intent.putExtra("phone", restaurants.getPhone());
    intent.putExtra("rate", restaurants.getRate());
    intent.putExtra("cost", restaurants.getCost());
    intent.putExtra("delivery", restaurants.getHasDelivery());
    intent.putExtra("parking", restaurants.getHasParking());
    intent.putExtra("bar", restaurants.getHasBar());
    intent.putExtra("card", restaurants.getHasCards());
    intent.putExtra("terrace", restaurants.getHasTerrace());
    intent.putExtra("reserve", restaurants.getHasReservation());
    intent.putExtra("wifi", restaurants.getHasWifi());
    infoView.setOnClickListener(this);
    return infoView;


    }
@Override
public void onClick(View infoView){
    //passing restaurants data to an intent.

    infoView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

the error I am getting is "cannot resolve intent" and when I pass "intent" to the onClick method I am getting an error says"cannot override its superclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` and put your code in `onInfoWindowClick()` to start a new activity

```
 map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        Restaurants restaurants = places.get(marker);
        Log.d(TAG,"restaurants1"+ restaurants.getName());
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, RestaurantDetailsActivity.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "lat" + restaurants.getLat());
        Log.d(TAG, "lng" + restaurants.getLng());
        intent.putExtra("id", restaurants.getId());
        intent.putExtra("name", restaurants.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure where should I put the piece of code, I have tried to put it outside the prepareView method but I got an error, I moved it to onMapReady(), I am getting  "cannot resolve OnInfoWindowClickListener()"

Comment: put it inside onCreate()..also you have to impprt the listener..ALT+ENTER then import class

Comment: Thanks!, for some reason Android Studio did not auto import it.

Answer (score 0):

Intent is local object that's why it does not found. Make it global.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, RestaurantDetailsActivity.class);

@Override
public void onClick(View infoView){
    //passing restaurants data to an intent.

    infoView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

And also remove below line from `prepareInfoWindow()` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, RestaurantDetailsActivity.class);
```

Comment: I just did it, there is no compile error, however when I click on the window view on the app I am not getting any response or errors.